removing AWS resources owned by another account id?
I recently inherited an AWS account and there's an old, obsolete VPC in there that I'm trying to decom. The VPC has several resources which are apparently owned by another account - one security group and two ENIs. Based on the descriptions, the ENIs appear to be from Lambda but they are not in use or attached to anything. The SG is attached to the ENIs. All three show the external account id in the 'Owner' field. I can't delete these because I do not "own" them, and as a consequence I can't delete the subnets they're associated with or the parent VPC.
I'm not clear on how these resources originally came to be in this account, and I'm not sure I understand how an ENI could be shared from or owned by another account to begin with. Initially I thought this might have been another account in the same AWS organization, but I reached out to our corporate IT folks and they assured me there is no such account id in our AWS org.
There are no VPC peering connections to any other VPCs with the suspect account id as either the requester or accepter. There are no stale SG rules listed for the VPC in question. There are no transit gateways touching that VPC. There are no VPC endpoints in that VPC. There's nothing shared in Resource Access Manager.
I don't know who owns that external account and my understanding is Amazon does not give out information about accounts not owned by you.
What can I do to get rid of these resources? What else can I check?
Thanks.
